# Select only the lines that have the a group letters

Tags: pyqgis, select

I have the following code:

```
from qgis.core import *

import processing
layer = QgsVectorLayer('C:\Test\Shapes\box.shp',
'box', 'ogr')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

query ='"Name" = "AAA"' and '"Func" != 1'

selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
layer.setSelectedFeatures([k.id() for k in selection])
```

And Im trying to select only the lines that have the letters "AAA" in Name. The problem is that, this select everything that have that have similar code, like "AA" and "AAB, but i only want the "AAA" ones.

Can any of you help me?

I have tried different things but nothing work.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data? Ian Turton should be right. The following query part:

    "NR_CAMARA" = 'CVT'

should not return True if for values like 'CV' and 'CVC'

Try the expression on QGIS first, it will help.

Answer (score 2):

I think your line

```
query ='"Name" = "AAA"' and '"Func" != 1'
```

is not doing what you think it is. It is doing an `AND` of the 2 strings which may well be true. You want something like:

```
query ='"Name" = \'AAA\' and "Func" != 1'
```

so the whole query is a string, everything in `"` is a column name and `'` is a literal.